# git: can't push changes after using filter-branch to remove file

Tags: git, push, git-filter-branch

I have an app on heroku, and unfortunately our git repository had some files that shouldn't be in it committed from the beginning.

But now other people are about to collaborate in the project and those files are always creating merge conflicts, so I need to remove that. I've used this command to successfully remove those files from all commit history:

`git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch -r foldername' HEAD`

But I can't push those changes to the server, I'm forced to pull before, therefore losing my changes through filter-branch.

How can I push those changes to the server so we won't have conflict issues anymore?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try `git push --force` yet? If so, does the server forbid forced pushed?

Comment: I... did not know about that :( It worked perfectly, I can't accept your comment as an answer, though. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `git push --force` will not force you to pull, that is it will skip the check for a common ancestor. The server can forbid the usage of that option though, at least with a hook.

A note on rewriting pushed history in general: It's okay if you're sure that nobody else cloned the repository yet. Otherwise rewriting history is a big no-no as it will cause a lot of trouble for people who are working on their own branches. (An exception to this can be the develop/pu branch as e.g. the official git repository uses. In their setup, the branch will be regularly reset to master, usually after a new release or similar, and that action is well documented so it shouldn't surprise anyone.)